# Time Picker doesn't render correctly in landscape

Tags: codenameone

I created the default hello world app and replaced the initial code with DateTimpicker sample to test it out. When I click on the time only field in portrait everything looks fine. If I rotate the app and then click on the time picker it is not right. I'm adding images to show the issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Portrait**
[image: Portrait]

**Landscape**
[image: Landscape]

Comment: I'll need some more details such as device OS version/brand etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm seeing with this code:

```
Form hi = new Form("Time Picker");

Picker p = new Picker();
p.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);
hi.add(p);

hi.show();
```

When opening in landscape:

[image]

When opening in portrait and rotating to landscape:

[image]